# Refrescar WebView Android Studio con Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

Necesito refrescar, o volver a cargar la pagina asociada al webview desde javascript justo despues de guardar unos datos, pero no me lo permite.
Estoy utilizando una clase JavaScriptInterface que me permitio enviar valores provenientes de android studio a mi pagina web asociada al webview, ahora lo que necesito es una vez de haber hecho la insercion de datos que me refresque la pagina pero no lo hace.
Intente con esto

```java
@JavascriptInterface
    public void reloadWebView(){
        IndexActivity.webViewIndex.reload();
        //IndexActivity.webViewIndex.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
    }
```

en la clase JavaScriptInterface  pero no hace la recarga de la pagina.
Desde Javascript lo consumo asi

```
 alert("Cuestionario guardado con exito");
 //location.reload();
 Android.reloadWebView();
```

En la clase IndexActiviy asocio el webview a la clase JavaScriptInterface  asi

```java
webViewIndex.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

Alguna solucion para poder recargar la webview desde javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
location.reload();
```

o lo que es lo mismo,

```
window.location.reload();
```

Referencia a la documentación de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Esta función la podes llamar después del alert en tu caso.

Si queres refrescar el WebView desde Android, deberías hacer un callback hacia el Activity que tenga tu WebView para poder usarlo y refrescar.

Comment: Android no reconoceel location.reload() de javascript

Comment: probaste haciendo window.location.reload()??

Comment: Abre el navergador, no recarga el webview de android.

Comment: vas a tener que pasarle un callback al JavaScriptInterface para avisarle al Activity que tenga tu webview que queres recargar el webview. En ese callback, que vas a tener acceso al webview, podes llamar al metodo "reload()" o "loadUrl(webview.getUrl())"